# How to set block visibility by role in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, blocks

In Drupal 7 it was easy to set block visibility by role in "block configuration" page.

How it can be done in Drupal 8?

Comment: Should be the same, you should have an option for role when in the block viability configuration. If not something has gone wrong with your setup. What version of drupal 8 are you on?

Comment: I have the latest one, the 8.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a discussion about this here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2952962

And solution in 28 worked for me:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2952962#comment-12549257